# Is this distribution discrete or continuous?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm reading a paper and have some issues on understanding it. Given the distribution function (or CDF) $F_X(x)$ with $x$ be complex, let $x = re^{-i\theta}$. Then $\theta$ is uniformly distributed and independent with $r$ and the disitribution function of $r$ is discrete and has finite number of mass points (let say it has $N$ points). The PDF of $X$ is represented as $f_X(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N p_k \delta(x-x_k)$, where $p_k$ and $x_k$ are the weight and the sample respectively and $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Diract delta function.

My questions are: Is distribution of $\theta$ continuous or discrete? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. I think you're just confused as to what the author means and you've transferred your confusion into your question. (1) CDFs are usually defined for *real* valued random variables, not complex. Are you sure $F_X$ is for a *complex* RV? (2) You introduce $\theta$ and explicitly say it's uniform. That's most certainly continuous. (3) You provide an explicit formula for the density of $X$ that's clearly discrete. You probably mean that formula to be the density for $r$, not $X$. Is that right?

Comment: One more comment: (4) If the given pdf for $X$ were correct, then $\theta$ would obviously be discrete, contradicting the assertion that $\theta$ is uniform.